# Why sticky header is not working in form tags when I use bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Why the form inputs or buttons are overlapping my navigation header?
Its working properly when I'm not using bootstrap 4.

I want the header to be on top of all objects in my website.

Is there a way to fix this using bootstrap only without using additional Javascript?

[Image Error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFlR2.jpg)

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.top-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}

.form-control {
 width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container-fluid">
<div class="top-container">
<h1>Main Header</h1>
<p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div class="header" id="myHeader">
<h2 class = "navbar fixed-top">Navigation Header</h2>
</div>

<div class="content">
  
<div class = "row">
  <div class = "col-sm-12">
    <form action = "#" method = "post">
      <div class = "form-group">
        <label>Name:</label>
         <input type = "text" name = "name" class = "form-control" />
       </div>
     </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Set the position fixed top... Of  the nave bar

Comment: class="navbar fixed-top

Comment: Use this bootstrap class.. Your css

Comment: Thank you but it overlaps the main header. Here's my setup
Main Header - 
Navigation Header (this should be the sticky or fixed part) - 
then Content - 
then Footer